# MLlib regexTokenizer is ignoring accents

Tags: regex, tokenize, apache-spark-mllib

I'm testing MLlib Tokenizer with pySpark(Python3) this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, RegexTokenizer

# Creating dataframe
sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
(["Eu acho que MLlib é incrível!"]),
(["Muito mais legal do que scikit-learn"])
], ["raw"])

# Putting sequential indexer on DataFrame
w = Window.orderBy('raw')
sentenceData = sentenceData.withColumn("id", row_number().over(w))

# Configuring regexTokenizer
regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="raw", outputCol="words", pattern="\\W")

# Applying Tokenizer to dataset
sentenceData = regexTokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

sentenceData.select(
   'id','raw','words'
).show(truncate=False)
```

The results is this:

```
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|id |raw                                 |words                                       |
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|1  |Eu acho que MLlib é incrível!       |[eu, acho, que, mllib, incr, vel]           |
|2  |Muito mais legal do que scikit-learn|[muito, mais, legal, do, que, scikit, learn]|
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the word 'incrível'(portuguese word means 'amazing') was transformed to two "new words" because of the character 'í'. I didn't find nothing on documentation to solve that. So, I'm lost here!

I'd tried to change the 'pattern' on 'regexTokenizer' config including the 'í' directly and other patterns including '\w' char in a "class" pattern (something like pattern="[\Wí\w]+"), but didn't work! There is some way to set 'portuguese' or force Spark some way in pattern to not ignore the accents ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pattern="[\\p{L}\\w]+"
```

It works for me by using Scala code as follows:

```
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setGaps(false)
                .setPattern("[\\p{L}\\w]+")
                .setInputCol("raw")
                .setOutputCol("words")
```